# regular expression to capture a version number

Tags: regex, sed, awk, grep

I have a line like this

```
<zimlet name="com_feeder_sugarbee" version="0.7.1" description="Sugar Bee v0.7.1">
```

I want to extract only the string 0.7.1

What tools would you suggest ?

I tried sed, awk, grep... I'm not good at any of them.

**Edit**

In what languages/tools are patterns like ".+?" and ".*?" supposed to return the shortest match possible ? I'm sure I saw this somewhere but can't remember where.

Comment: I think perl has a language construct to give you the shortest possible match for an RE, but that's very rarely needed. Usually instead of ".+", you actually want "[^X]+" where X is some delimiting character - trying to use ".+" is usually the result of someone just not thinking it through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F\" '{print $4}' file
```

and here's some useless text because this goofy web interface won't accept an answer shorter than 30 characters.

Comment: `awk -F\" -e '/version/ {print $4}' file` works just fine ! thanks

Comment: With this trick, even `grep version com_feeder_sugarbee.xml | cut -d '"' -f 4` works just as well.
`

Comment: yes but why use 2 tools and a pipe when one tool will do the job.

Answer (score 5):

One way using `sed`:

```
sed -n 's/.*version="\([^"]*\).*/\1/p' file
```

Or, if your version of `grep` supports Perl-regex:

```
grep -oP '(?<=version=")[^"]*' file
```

Result:

```
0.7.1
```

Comment: I was going to answer something like this, but couldn't remember bash syntax (used to python). The secret here is that you look for "everything that is not a quote, multiple times" (`[^"]*`) after the first quote, until you find the closing quote.

Comment: Can anybody guess why isn't this working ? `grep -oP '(?<=version=").*?(?<=")' file`, what I inteded to write is : match version=" (but ignore it in the output) followed by the shortest string that precedes a second ". That's .*? (shortest string) and (?<=") was supposed to say preceding a ". Any ideas ?

Comment: @ychaouche: You are close, try: `grep -oP '(?<=version=").*?(?=")' file`. You may want read up on [lookahead and lookbehind assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). HTH.

Comment: Thanks, worked finely. That link was a good ressource, thanks for that too.